# Laravel: resource was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

I am developing a Laravel 7 website for web and API. I have completed the API and I can call all routes there but I have got an error when trying to access a route on the web.php

```
Route::get("/products", 'web\ProductController@index')->name("products.all");
```

the error says

> The requested resource /products was not found on this server.

I have run route:list command and the route is listed there.this is what it prints

```
[{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD","uri":"\/","name":null,"action":"Closure","middleware":"web"},{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD","uri":"api\/documentation","name":"l5-swagger.api","action":"L5Swagger\\Http\\Controllers\\SwaggerController@api","middleware":""},{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD","uri":"api\/oauth2-callback","name":"l5-swagger.oauth2_callback","action":"L5Swagger\\Http\\Controllers\\SwaggerController@oauth2Callback","middleware":""},{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD","uri":"docs\/asset\/{asset}","name":"l5-swagger.asset","action":"L5Swagger\\Http\\Controllers\\SwaggerAssetController@index","middleware":""},{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS","uri":"docs\/{jsonFile?}","name":"l5-swagger.docs","action":"L5Swagger\\Http\\Controllers\\SwaggerController@docs","middleware":""},{"domain":null,"method":"GET|HEAD","uri":"products","name":"products.all","action":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\web\\ProductController@index","middleware":"web"}]
```

and the controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{    
    public function index()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what full route you are getting in list please paste here

Comment: I've added them on the post.

Comment: what is directory architecture of your controller

Comment: I did post my controller in the question now.

Comment: Controllers\web\ProductController.php

Answer (score 0):

```
use this Route::namespace('web')->group(function () {
    Route::get("/products", 'ProductController@index')->name("products.all");

});
```

and use php artisan key:generate

Comment: داداش کجاش گیری؟
قسمت پروداکت کنترلر ایندکس رو بفرست

Comment: in the controller index, I currently returning a hard coded 1 as a returned value ( return 1;) but it is not excuted

Comment: share controller index method

Comment: I did in the post

Comment: share me all source

Comment: I didn't understand. What are the source that I should share?

Comment: in the web.php, I only have this route and the main one "/" that runs a closure to show the default laravel welcome page .